# In Java, how to set the header of a Restlet Response?

Tags: java, http-headers, response, restlet

I can't seem to figure out how to add headers to my restlet response. When I look at the available methods in the `Response` object, all I see is `setStatus`, `setEntity`, and `setAttributes` but none of these tell me how to set custom http headers on the response.

For example, I have a `GET` call the returns something like the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/json
Content-Length: 123
Some-Header: the value
Some-Other-Header: another value

{
  id: 111,
  value: "some value this could be anything",
  diagnosis: {
    start: 12552255,
    end: 12552261,
    key: "ABC123E11",
    source: "S1",
  }
}
```

Whatever it maybe. In the `handleGet` method, I handle it like so:

```
final MediaType textJsonType = new MediaType("text/json");

@Override
public void handleGet() {
  log.debug("Handling GET...");
  final Response res = this.getResponse();

  try {
    final MyObject doc = this.getObj("hello", 1, "ABC123E11", "S1");
    final String docStr = doc.toString();

    res.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
    res.setEntity(docStr, textJsonType);

    // need to set Some-header, and Some-other-header here!
  }
  catch(Throwable t) {
    res.setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
    res.setEntity(new TextRepresentation(t.toString()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering why you're overriding `handleGet` in your `Resource`. In Restlet 1.1, you'd probably want to use `represent` instead (and let `handleGet` do its logic (including things like content-type negotiation as far as I remember); in Restlet 2, you'd probably want to override `get()` in the `ServerResource` or use the `@Get` annotation.

Comment: @Bruno, It seems like every example I see on the internet does this differently. I will go ahead and start using `represent` instead of handleGet. But do you know how I would handle `PUT` and `DELETE` as well?

Comment: In Restlet 1.1, it's `storeRepresentation` for PUT and `removeRepresentation` for DELETE (see [the first resource tutorial](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/firstResource#part01)). You might as well use Restlet 2 nowadays (in which case it's `put(Representation)` and `delete()`, or you can use the `@Put` and `@Delete` annotations instead).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Restlet is more about the REST architectural principles than HTTP, it tries to be protocol agnostic and doesn't expose the HTTP headers directly. However, they are stored in the `org.restlet.http.headers` attribute of the response (as a `Form`). Note that you can only set custom headers this way, not standard ones (these are handled directly by the framework, e.g. `Content-Type` depends on the `Representation`'s `MediaType`).

See this for an example:
http://blog.arc90.com/2008/09/15/custom-http-response-headers-with-restlet/ (link content also available from the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150506105646/http://blog.arc90.com/2008/09/15/custom-http-response-headers-with-restlet)).

Comment: @E_net4, I've added another link.

Comment: Both Link are broken, can you please put the example in your answer? Thanks